# Apache POI OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm running into a problem while processing .xlsx files with Apache POI.  I've read through many of the threads on StackOverflow, as well as support on the Intellij and Oracle sites, and I've tried implementing the recommended fixes.  I still get an out of memory error any time the JVM tries to process an excel file > 5 MB.  For reference, I'm on an iMac with 8 GB RAM and I've stepped up JVM RAM allocation to its current level of 4 GB (512 MB at a time) with no luck.

The program I'm building processes all excel spreadsheets in a directory and adds unique values from a field in to a HashSet.  The resulting HashSet will be written to a file once all spreadsheets have been processed.

Anytime a file > 5 MB is encountered, whether it is the first file processed or the last file processed, the GC can't keep up and I get an out of memory exception.  5 MB seems to be my limit for successfully reading in and processing an excel file.  It seems odd to me that a file just over 5 MB would be hose the system for resources so badly, so I'm wondering if the problem might be in my code?  Major methods below. Thoughts?

```
    public class Launcher {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            WVDataFileReader reader = new WVDataFileReader();
            HashSet<String> operators = reader.getOperatorsFromExcel("data/WV/production", 2);
            FileOutput.writeToFile(operators, "/db/mysql/mysql-files/operators");
        }
    }


public abstract class RegulatoryDataFileReader {

    private final String EXCEL_EXTENSION = "xlsx";
    protected static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RegulatoryDataFileReader.class.getName());


    protected abstract HashSet<String> processSheetForOperators(Sheet sheet, int firstDataRow, HashSet<String> set);

    public HashSet<String> getOperatorsFromExcel(String directory, int firstDataRow) {

        HashSet<String> temp = new HashSet<>(); 
        ArrayList<File> spreadsheets = getExcelFiles(directory); 
        Collections.sort(spreadsheets);

        for (File excelFile : spreadsheets) {
            System.out.println("Reading data from " + excelFile.getName());

            try {
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excelFile);
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Assumes spreadsheet has 1 sheet

                processSheetForOperators(sheet, firstDataRow, temp);

                workbook.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }



    public class WVDataFileReader extends RegulatoryDataFileReader {

        @Override
        public HashSet<String> processSheetForOperators(Sheet sheet, int firstDataRow, HashSet<String> set) {
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                // Skip to the first row containing data
                for (int i = 1; i < firstDataRow; i++) {
                    rowIterator.next();
                }

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    int columnNum = 0;
                    Row row = rowIterator.next(); // Advance row
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        columnNum++;
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); // Advance cell

                        switch (columnNum) {
                            case 4:
                                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                String operator = cell.getStringCellValue();
                                operator = StrUtils.cleanString(operator);;
                                set.add(operator);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return set;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The way POI handles `xlsx` files in the usermodel API *is* horribly inefficient. Unlike `xls`, which is handled with poi-specific code, `xlsx` files are handled with some generic xml to oo library inflating every data item into an object, encapsulating an expensive DOM tree. If you only want to iterate the contents, you might look at POI’s streaming API, the table at the end of [this page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) compares the approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I can't believe that the usermodel could be THAT inefficient -- that's ridiculous.  My xlsx files have ~50,000 rows of 38 numeric columns + 1 String column containing (on average) about 20 characters.  In terms of raw data, the cell data itself should consume slightly less than 20 MB of memory by itself.  It seems so odd to me that the Apache POI would require several GB of overhead to wrap such a small amount of data, which is why I thought the error might be on my end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only reading the xlsx file I would try using this library that lowers the memory used by Apache POI. https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader

Please note that not all of the methods of the Apache POI API are implemented, so it may not address your specific use case.

The issue is that Apache POI uses a ton of memory, and usage seems to go up depending on the number of rows and columns in the Excel (even if they are empty). In my case I was getting an out of memory error for an Excel document that was only 2MB.